# From .NET 4.0 add reference to assembly in .NET 4.6

Tags: .net-4.0, compatibility, .net-4.6

Visual Studio 2019 allows in the .NET 4.0 project Tests.Test_4_0.vbproj to add a reference to the .NET 4.6 assembly Tests.Test_4_6.dll. The editor allows to call methods of class Test1 in the .NET 4.6 assembly. However, when I build the project, I get the error:

```
C:\temp\Test_4_0.vb(327,35): error BC30002: Type 'Tests.Test_4_6.Test1' is not defined.
```

Is there some way to call .NET 4.6 functions from .NET 4.0?